# INFO: Page fetched successfully WARN: No metatags found ,But i can see those meta tags on view page source in Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

[image]

View page source code the meta tags are shown

```html
<meta data-n-head="ssr" charset="utf-8">
<meta data-n-head="ssr" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="description" name="description" content="Welcome to iMeWeUs,Login To Your Account To Make Memories">
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="twitter:card" name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="twitter:site" name="twitter:site" content="@nuxt_js">
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="twitter:url" name="twitter:url" content="https://dev-kutumbh-app.netlify.app/">
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="og:site_name" property="og:site_name" content="iMeWeUs">
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="og:type" property="og:type" content="website">
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="og:url" property="og:url" content="https://dev-kutumbh-app.netlify.app/">
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="twitter:title" name="twitter:title" content="nnnn">
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="twitter:description" name="twitter:description" content="travel">
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="twitter:image" name="twitter:image" content="https://dev-kutumbh-repository.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/profileImage/60d9adae350c6a001c767bb4/riverjpg/1627285203543_riverjpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIA4WAYB4JYLDKCHMLT%2F20210728%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20210728T082909Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=604800&amp;X-Amz-Signature=35be8c0da1b1818f82a170d947eb062d7d708c377660b30e128d7e93067baee7&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host">
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="twitter:image:alt" name="twitter:image:alt" content="nnnn">
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="og:title" property="og:title" content="nnnn">
```

Comment: Looking at the source code located here, there is a HUGE amount of code and it takes some time to parse it properly. Maybe the twitter validator is kinda time-outing here. view-source:https://dev-kutumbh-app.netlify.app/ Can't you reduce the amount of CSS here? It may help the validator.

Comment: Also, can you share your `nuxt.config.js` and properly indent + highlight it?

Comment: sure will try ,any ither way to resolve it

Comment: Before even solving it, we need to understand what is happening here. I know that you have some quite huge meta tags, maybe trying something smaller and checking again (without as many CSS) may help.

Comment: Lastly, isn't your URL (the path that you give to the validator), protected by a password? Can you link it yo us to see if we have access to it.

Comment: actually the url that I give to card validator is link of one page in our application....,and the application is password protected ..where each user having their username and password.

Comment: Yeah, so I don't know how much this is protected but you probably cannot access it (aka Twitter cannot access it) if it's behind a password.